# Eliminating quoted column names from row column pivot script

Tags: postgresql

I have a rows to columns problem for which I found a very nice solution by hnsl on gitub called [colpivot](https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot), the script of which below

colpivot takes a table like this:

```
   User Descriptor Value
     1   IsMarried    true
     1   IsMale       true
     1   IsEmployed   false
     2   IsMarried    false
     2   IsMale       false
     2   IsEmployed   false
```

And produces a table like this:

```
'User'  'IsMarried' 'IsMale' 'IsEmployed'     
  1          true      true         false 
  2          false     false        false
```

which is great, exactly what I want **except for the single quotes** around the column name.

I have tried monkeying for several hours with the script but I am T-SQL person and can't seem to quite work out the PSQL to avoid quoting the column names.

I'm sure it has something to do with the various 'quote_ident' or quote_literal functions in this script but I keep picking the wrong ones to eliminate I guess.   (I realize the script will break if I do this with a table with column names that require quoting, but having to 4-quote every column name will in my queries will very tedious as the actual use case has a lot of logic and many columns. )

Maybe somebody more experience can spot the solution quickly?

```
-- Copyright © 2015, Hannes Landeholm <hannes@jumpstarter.io>
-- This Source Code Form is suaubject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
-- License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
-- file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

-- See the README.md file distributed with this project for documentation.
create or replace function colpivot(
    out_table varchar, in_query varchar,
    key_cols varchar[], class_cols varchar[],
    value_e varchar, col_order varchar
) returns void as $$
    declare
        in_table varchar;
        col varchar;
        ali varchar;
        on_e varchar;
        i integer;
        rec record;
        query varchar;
        -- This is actually an array of arrays but postgres does not support an array of arrays type so we flatten it.
        -- We could theoretically use the matrix feature but it's extremly cancerogenous and we would have to involve
        -- custom aggrigates. For most intents and purposes postgres does not have a multi-dimensional array type.
        clsc_cols text[] := array[]::text[];
        n_clsc_cols integer;
        n_class_cols integer;
    begin
        in_table := quote_ident('__' || out_table || '_in');
        execute ('create temp table ' || in_table || ' on commit drop as ' || in_query);
        -- get ordered unique columns (column combinations)
        query := 'select array[';
        i := 0;
        foreach col in array class_cols loop
            if i > 0 then
                query := query || ', ';
            end if;
            query := query || 'quote_literal(' || quote_ident(col) || ')';
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        query := query || '] x from ' || in_table;
        for j in 1..2 loop
            if j = 1 then
                query := query || ' group by ';
            else
                query := query || ' order by ';
                if col_order is not null then
                    query := query || col_order || ' ';
                    exit;
                end if;
            end if;
            i := 0;
            foreach col in array class_cols loop
                if i > 0 then
                    query := query || ', ';
                end if;
                query := query || quote_ident(col);
                i := i + 1;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        -- raise notice '%', query;
        for rec in
            execute query
        loop
            clsc_cols := array_cat(clsc_cols, rec.x);
        end loop;
        n_class_cols := array_length(class_cols, 1);
        n_clsc_cols := array_length(clsc_cols, 1) / n_class_cols;
        -- build target query
        query := 'select ';
        i := 0;
        foreach col in array key_cols loop
            if i > 0 then
                query := query || ', ';
            end if;
            query := query || '_key.' || quote_ident(col) || ' ';
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        for j in 1..n_clsc_cols loop
            query := query || ', ';
            col := '';
            for k in 1..n_class_cols loop
                if k > 1 then
                    col := col || ', ';
                end if;
                col := col || clsc_cols[(j - 1) * n_class_cols + k];
            end loop;
            ali := '_clsc_' || j::text;
            query := query || '(' || replace(value_e, '#', ali) || ')' || ' as ' || quote_ident(col) || ' ';
        end loop;
        query := query || ' from (select distinct ';
        i := 0;
        foreach col in array key_cols loop
            if i > 0 then
                query := query || ', ';
            end if;
            query := query || quote_ident(col) || ' ';
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        query := query || ' from ' || in_table || ') _key ';
        for j in 1..n_clsc_cols loop
            ali := '_clsc_' || j::text;
            on_e := '';
            i := 0;
            foreach col in array key_cols loop
                if i > 0 then
                    on_e := on_e || ' and ';
                end if;
                on_e := on_e || ali || '.' || quote_ident(col) || ' = _key.' || quote_ident(col) || ' ';
                i := i + 1;
            end loop;
            for k in 1..n_class_cols loop
                on_e := on_e || ' and ';
                on_e := on_e || ali || '.' || quote_ident(class_cols[k]) || ' = ' || clsc_cols[(j - 1) * n_class_cols + k];
            end loop;
            query := query || 'left join ' || in_table || ' as ' || ali || ' on ' || on_e || ' ';
        end loop;
        -- raise notice '%', query;
        execute ('create temp table ' || quote_ident(out_table) || ' on commit drop as ' || query);
        -- cleanup temporary in_table before we return
        execute ('drop table ' || in_table)
        return;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;here
```

Comment: Why can't you handle those single quotes in the presentation layer?  Maybe you can explain why they present such a problem for you.

Comment: Its not a presentation layer issue actually. I'm running ad hoc queries against this table in rails and constructing query strings in ruby with all the escaped single and double quotes gets quite tedious  Not that it this has much to do with the question.

Comment: Do you have any idea which line of code is quoting the column names?  Maybe there is a minimally painful fix possible.

Comment: That's actually the question I'm asking here.